# httpClient on error refreshes the url in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-errorhandler

I am trying to use `httpClient` in `Angular` to make API calls. Here is my code where I am making the api call.

This is my `httpPost` method in `authService`:

```
this.authService.httpPost("/api/Users/requestNew", payload).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.inputForm.reset();
  },
  (error) => {
    let errorMessage = "Ooooops. An error occured. Please refresh and try again.";

  }
);
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
constructor(
  private http: HttpClient, 
  private dataService: DataService
) {}

httpPost(url, payload) {
  return this.http.post(
    this.url_base + ":" + this.port + url,
    payload, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem("id_token")
      })
    }
  );
}
```

Now, in the payload I am intentionally missing a field, as a result the server is throwing an error. This is the error I get from the server:

```
http://192.168.0.15:3000/api/Users/requestNew 450 (unknown)
```

Response from server:

```
{"error":{"statusCode":"450","message":"Duration is not set.","code":"MISSING_FIELD"}}
```

Now the problem I am facing is my page gets refreshed automatically. This was my original url: `http://localhost:4200/user/new`, after api call the page gets refreshed with this new url `http://localhost:4200/user/new?`. An extra question mark is getting added and I am not sure why the page is getting refreshed. It should not be refreshed as no where in my logic I have written so.

**Edit**

I have a `formGroup`

```
inputForm: FormGroup;
durationsControl: FormControl = new FormControl(null, [
  Validators.required
]);

ngOnInit(){
    this.inputForm = new FormGroup({
      duration: this.durationsControl,
      //more controls
    });
}
```

on change of a dropdown I am removing this control:

```
valueCHanged(e) {
  const type = e.value;
  if (type === "One") {
    this.durationDiv.nativeElement.style.display = "none";
    this.inputForm.removeControl("duration");

  } else {
    this.durationDiv.nativeElement.style.display = "block";
    this.inputForm.addControl("duration", this.durationsControl);
  }
}
```

If I do not remove the duration control `(this.inputForm.removeControl("duration");)`, then it works perfectly. How is this change resulting in page refresh?

**Edit1**
I removed the `duration` control from `ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.inputForm = new FormGroup({
          // duration: this.durationsControl, ---> removed this
          //more controls
        });
    }
```

Now it is working fine and the page is not getting refreshed. But I am still not able to figure out the reason.

Comment: My quick guess is, you have a `button` on your page, on clicking of that is making page post back..

Comment: I have debugged and found out the problem.I have a `formGroup` and I am dynamically removing a `control` from it based on a dropdown. If I do not remove the `formControl` it works perfectly. I am not sure how removing a control from formGroup results in this behavior,

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about :)

Comment: @helloworld, add your Component Code as well where you're removing the `formControl` dynamically. Not sure why you'd do that in the first place though?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Added. Please have a look at the code. The entire code is quite lengthy, so just added the relevant portion.

Comment: @PankajParkar I figured out the portion of the code which was causing this issue, but am not able to come up with an explanation. I have updated the question, if you get the time, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're removing the control from the `form` but it's respective template is still lying on the Component template and hence this issue. Not really sure though.